# add 3 column value, find out the results in ascending order and prioritize the result

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a table here.

I want to add  (3 different column cell) value, find out the largest to smallest value in an ascending order or sorting them, and then return the results as a priority basis such as: after adding 3 column value for each cell, which would be the largest its priority can be defined as 1,  second largest value can be defined as 2, third largest can be 3...thus go on.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Your description, as is, is hard to understand. A simple example would help. Are you looking for a VBA macro or just the steps?

Comment: an example: 
suppose collumn1-2

Comment: lets say
A1=2 ,B1=3 ,c1=4
A2=4,B2=5,C2=6
A3=1,B3=2,C3=7
Add- A1,B1,c1; A2,B2,C2; A3,B3,C3
return the sum result from largest to smallest and  prioritize them,

Comment: I am looking for the code. not VBA or Macro

Comment: In D1 you can add the formula `=SUM(A1:C1)` and fill down. Sort on ColumnD.

Comment: I added an example if not correct, I can fix it. As already suggested, select the area and sort by the sum column.

Comment: What's wrong with the [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) and either the [RANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANK-function-6A2FC49D-1831-4A03-9D8C-C279CF99F723) or [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db)?

Comment: summing and sorting and at the same time return the corresponding row depending on the sorted result all should be done by one statement.

Comment: I think that's awesome . Thank you so much . This site is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in G5,

```
=LARGE(INDEX((A$1:A$3)+(B$1:B$3)+(C$1:C$3), , ), ROW(1:1))
```

Fill down.

[image: LAREG_INDEX_rANK]